# Find method and append code to the method using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have two pages names like Default.aspx and ChangePage.aspx. In Default.aspx page, i have a button called **Modify Method**. Once i Click on the button I have to find out a method name called **GetName** and append a string to the method, which is located in **ChangePage.aspx.cs**. Is there a way to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes, .cs-files are pretty much just textfiles, so change the abbreviation to .txt and use streamreader and streamwriter as you need